# Concatenating bits

Tags: c, bit

I have have to concatenate the bits of the int. For example:

```
unsigned char byte1 = 0x0F;   // 00001111
unsigned char byte2 = 0xCC;   // 11001100
unsigned char byte3 = 0x55;   // 01010101
unsigned char byte4 = 0x04;   // 00000100
```

After concatenation the result should be:

```
00000100010101011100110000001111
```

I tried doing smth like:

```
unsigned int temp = 0;
temp = temp | byte1; //the result should be 00001111 for now

temp = temp >> 8;
byte2 = byte2 << 8;
temp = temp | byte2; //the result should be 1100110000001111 for now

temp = temp >> 8;
byte3 = byte3 << 8;
temp = temp | byte3; //the result should be 010101011100110000001111 for now

temp = temp >> 8;
byte4 = byte4 << 8;
temp = temp | byte4; //the result should be 00000100010101011100110000001111
```

But when I print the temp, it shows 0:

```
printf("%d", temp) //===> gives 0
```

Comment: @RNar, what do you mean ?

Comment: sorry, I misread your code

Comment: You should use `unsigned int` (or `uint32_t` preferably) and make sure your bytes are also `unsigned char`, not plain or signed char. Otherwise you will run into issues because in C, `|` and `<<` are arithmetic operations.

Comment: update the question to show how `byte1` etc. are declared and initialized. For example if it is `unsigned char byte2;` then the line `byte2 = byte2 << 8;` will set `byte2` to `0`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to unsigned int temp and byte1, byte2.. are of type unsigned char. But it still keeps giving me 0. @M.M

Comment: @M.M, why would byte2 = byte2 << 8;  set byte2 to 0??

Comment: Because `byte2 << 8` will end in eight zero bits , and when you try to store that in an eight-bit variable, all the higher bits get truncated

Comment: @M.M, then how can I keep all of the bits and concatenate to the result? Sorry for asking many questions.

Comment: @Maximillan we need to clarify the question first. I edited your code to reflect comments, can you confirm that my edit matches what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int byte1 = 0x0F; // 00001111; //byte1
unsigned int byte2 = 0xCC; // 11001100; //byte2
unsigned int byte3 = 0x55; // 01010101; //byte3
unsigned int byte4 = 0x04; // 00000100; //byte4

unsigned int temp = (byte1) | (byte2 << 8) | (byte3 << 16) | (byte4 << 24);
printf("%u", temp);
```

prints `72731663` which is `00000100010101011100110000001111`.

---

If you want to keep your inputs as `unsigned char`, then this has the same result:

```
unsigned char byte1 = 0x0F; // 00001111; //byte1
unsigned char byte2 = 0xCC; // 11001100; //byte2
unsigned char byte3 = 0x55; // 01010101; //byte3
unsigned char byte4 = 0x04; // 00000100; //byte4

unsigned int temp = byte4;
temp <<= 8;
temp |= byte3;
temp <<= 8;
temp |= byte2;
temp <<= 8;
temp |= byte1;
printf("%u", temp);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how (byte2 << 8) or other shifts do not end up with 0000000, @Adam? For example, byte2 is 11001100 and shifting it by 8, how come 11001100 << 8 does not end up with 0000000 considering the fact that byte2 is unsigned char? Thanks!

Comment: I only do `byte2 << 8` if `byte2` is an `unsigned int`. In that case there are at least 32 bits and the result only requires 16. I included this way because when I answered you still haven't specified the types of your 'byte' variables. Note that if `byte2` is an `unsigned char` (second half of answer) then I do not do `byte2 << 8` because like you say, it would absolutely zero it out.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it seems to me the

```
temp = temp >> 8;
```

bitshifts away your entire temp value.

Comment: probably yeah, if it's anything close to Java's bitwise operators OP should `<< 8` the current value then `|` it with the next one

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand the layout of your data.  The `temp = temp >> 8` always shifts out what you just added:

```
uint32_t temp = 0; // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
temp |= byte1;     // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
temp = temp >> 8;  // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
// and so on...
```

The bytes, when combined with larger numbers, are zero-extended on the left (not on the right), so shifting them to the right will remove them again.

There's two obvious ways of writing this:

The first is to shift the bytes left to the right place before or-ing them into the result:

```
uint32_t temp = 0;     // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
temp |= byte1;         // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
temp |= (byte2 <<  8); // 00000000 00000000 11001100 00001111
temp |= (byte3 << 16); // 00000000 01010101 11001100 00001111
temp |= (byte4 << 24); // 00000100 01010101 11001100 00001111
```

The other is to shift `temp` to the left (*not* to the right) and or-ing the bytes into it in their "normal" (un-shifted) place:

```
uint32_t temp = 0; // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
temp |= byte4;     // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
temp = temp << 8;  // 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000
temp |= byte3;     // 00000000 00000000 00000100 01010101
temp = temp << 8;  // 00000000 00000100 01010101 00000000
temp |= byte2;     // 00000000 00000100 01010101 11001100
temp = temp << 8;  // 00000100 01010101 11001100 00000000
temp |= byte1;     // 00000100 01010101 11001100 00001111
```

Both can be written concisely, as in:

```
uint32_t temp = (byte4 << 24) | (byte3 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | byte1;
```

or

```
uint32_t temp = ((byte4 << 8 | byte3) << 8 | byte2) << 8 | byte1;
```

Comment: When shifting to the left, for example byte2 << 8, doesn't it become 00000000?? @nobody

Comment: @Maximillan Essentially `x<<1` is `x*2`, and `x<<2` is `x*4` … or generally `x<<k` is `x * 2^k` (where `^` means exponentiation). `x>>k` is division by powers of two. For the computation `byte2 << 8`, `byte2` is expanded ("promoted") to an `int`. If you store the result in a `char`, it will be truncated and you'll get `00000000`. But if you assign the result to an `int`, the bits are preserved and you'll get `00000000 00000000 11001100 00000000`. (Compare "integer promotions" / "usual arithmetic conversion" in the C standard for the gory details, what I wrote is probably still simplified.)